# Can "passed on" be an alternative for "passed since"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I want to write the following for shortening and for translation accuracy from

> Do you know how many years have been passed **since your existence**?

to

> Do you know how many years have been passed **on you**?

Would the latter be a valid equivalent for the former? Because it is not correct to say/write:

> Do you know how many years have been passed **since you**?

According to my search, I found the verb "pass" come with *from* and *since* in this specific meaning but not with *on* except if the meaning would be: give, refuse, or die.

Comment: Is the first sentence a question asked to a ghost?

Comment: @JamesK _ Actually to a sea. The speaker is talking with it as if it was a person.

Comment: That is an important piece of context!  Does the sea exist when the person is talking to it?

Comment: @JamesK _ Yes, of course. The question, in fact, is: "Do you know how many thousands have been passed (since your existence / on you)?" - I have changed it a bit for simplicity.

Comment: By "changing for simplicity" you have also changed the meaning.  It is better to ask about the actual sentence. Now finally we still need some more context: Who is saying this?  Is this a quote from a book? Something that you made up? A situation that you have been in yourself? Did you see this written or did you hear it? (if heard are you sure it is "passed" and not "past").

Comment: @JamesK _ I'm sorry for the lack of the details (*I don't know why it has to happen each time I ask here*). I will definitely take into account what you have stated, but let it pass this time as I have got an answer based on what I exactly asked about, and I have already accepted it. However, and for what it's worth, this is a sentence from a poem, it is written originally in Arabic, and I'm currently translating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can understand what you are trying to say, none of your sentences really sound like natural English.  They are grammatical, but the word choice sounds like a direct translation from another language, and not how a native speaker might phrase the question.

As an expression of the *passing* of time, asking "How many years have passed since you were born" is grammatical, but odd without any context.  Most people would just ask:

> Do you know **how old you are**?

It's fine with other significant events.  Some examples:

> Do you know how many years have passed since you graduated high school?
>
> Do you know how many years have passed since you last visited your home town?
>
> Do you know how many years have passed since you spoke to your childhood friend?

"Passed on" is not a substitute for "passed since".  "Passed on" or just "passed" is actually a common euphemism for "died".

> Many years have passed since my grandmother **passed on**, but sometimes I speak to her as if she could still hear me.

"Pass on" can also describe an object (of some importance) that is *passed* from one person to another, usually in some formal context such as a legacy:

> Before my wedding, my mother **passed on** her wedding ring to me, and now I'm **passing** it **on** to you, my daughter.

Keep in mind that the usage of *pass* in "pass since" is somewhat figurative, as it metaphorically indicates the movement of time going by.  In the same way a person can "pass *by*" a friend without recognizing them, you can say something like:

> As I get older, sometimes it seems as if years can **pass by** without me even noticing.

Other phrasal verbs such as "pass *from*" and "pass *to*" are possible, but more difficult to fit into the metaphor related to the passage of time.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this informative answer, Andrew! So, do I conclude that the second structure is incorrect and is impossible to be rephrased correctly?

Comment: @TasneemZH  Actually there is an alternate use of "pass on" which I should include in my answer, but it doesn't have to do with the passage of time.

Comment: Please do. I would like to know it in any case.